# Incorrect plotting of data on Choropleth map with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fortify, choropleth

I am trying to make a Choropleth map of Germany using ggplot2. My data is a .csv file with 2 rows (*RS= containing numbers 1 to 16 for each German state & Tariff= 16 random positive and negative numbers*).

```
    RS  Tariff
1   01  -5.25
2   02  7.16
3   03  6.65
4   04  3.10
5   05  3.69
6   06  2.49
7   07  1.89
8   08  3.93
9   09  -5.84
10  10  -2.61
11  11  -0.21
12  12  2.35
13  13  -5.94
14  14  -7.54
15  15  -3.27
16  16  -8.75
```

Also I have a shape file [Germany shape file](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ae25571c60d94ce5b7fcbf74e27c00e0). What I want to do is to plot this positive and negative numbers onto map of germany for each state, with 2 colors (positive=Green and Negative=Red). Below is my code

```
library(XLConnect)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(DataCombine)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)

#### EEG Data Read ####
eeg<-read.csv(file = "data/testdata1.csv", skip = 0, sep = ",", dec=".",       header=TRUE)
colnames(eeg)<-c("RS", "Tariff")
eeg$RS<-   c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16")
eeg$RS<-as.factor(eeg$RS)
eeg$Tariff<- as.numeric(eeg$Tariff)

#### Shape Data Read ####
bundesl<-readOGR("data/new_shape/vg2500_bld.shp", "vg2500_bld")
bundesl@data<- bundesl@data[order(bundesl$RS, na.last=NA),]

### Rearrange shape data for better merging ###
levels(bundesl$GEN)<- c("Schleswig-Holstein", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",   "Hamburg", "Bremen", "Niedersachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Brandenburg", 
                    "Berlin", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Hessen","Thüringen","Sachsen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Saarland", "Baden-  Württemberg", "Bayern")
bundesl$GEN<- c("Schleswig-Holstein", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", "Hamburg", "Bremen", "Niedersachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Brandenburg", 
            "Berlin", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Hessen","Thüringen","Sachsen",  "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Saarland", "Baden-Württemberg", "Bayern")
bundesl$SHAPE_LENG<-  c("1217255.7","1780980.8","175253.8","154971.6","2016496.4","949096.8",
                   "1295460.4","180751.2","1352108","1105092.8","961942.7","979294.3","910650.4",
                   "282910.8","1298891.7","2046039.3")
bundesl$SHAPE_AREA<- c("15857425536","23044684847","760539820","405480872","47716406483","20494982327","29653902483","886480139","34047269991","21092318103","16178531941","18401642456","19834907486","2578541706","35801397076","70550070623")

# #### Shape Data und EEG Data join ####
bundesl@data<-merge(bundesl@data, eeg, by="RS",  all=TRUE)

# #### Shapes Plot ####
bundesl@data$id <- (as.numeric(rownames(bundesl@data))-1)
bundesl.df<-fortify(bundesland)
bundesl.df <- join(bundesl.df, bundesl@data, by="id")


 ggp <- ggplot(data=bundesl.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))
 ggp <- ggp + geom_polygon(aes(fill=Tariff), col="black") 
 ggp <- ggp + coord_map() 
 ggp <- ggp + scale_fill_continuous(name=expression(Tariff), low = "red", high = "green", space = "Lab", na.value = "white", guide = "colourbar")
ggp <- ggp + theme_minimal()
ggp <- ggp + theme(axis.title=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(),   axis.text=element_blank())
 ggp
```

So far I manage to plot the map, but with *wrong data mapping*. I mean state with positive Tariff like Schleswig-Holstein should be green but are red and Bavaria should be red but is green.

My guess is that there is problem with ***fortify function***. My data is only 16 rows but after fortify it print 1000+ rows. Why?? and this is something which is causing mismatching of data. I did all the search on internet I possibly can for the solution. I would appreciate if anybody can give me an answer as to why this problem is occurring.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`fortify` puts the polygons from the shapefile into something `ggplot` can plot, hence the 1,000+ rows. While you *can* attach values to the fortified polygons, it's not necessary.

So, you don't really have to go through all that trouble for the choropleth. Take a look at the following. I added in some extra bits to show which values get mapped to which `RS`:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

egg <- read.table(text="RS  Tariff
01  -5.25
02  7.16
03  6.65
04  3.10
05  3.69
06  2.49
07  1.89
08  3.93
09  -5.84
10  -2.61
11  -0.21
12  2.35
13  -5.94
14  -7.54
15  -3.27
16  -8.75", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("character", "numeric"))

bundesl <- readOGR("vg2500_geo84/vg2500_bld.shp", "vg2500_bld")
bundesl@data<- bundesl@data[order(bundesl$RS, na.last=NA),]

# good projection for germany but if you intende to draw additional
# lines or points you'll have to project them before plotting so this
# may be more trouble than it's worth and you can just use 
# coord_map("mollweide") or something else that works for you besides mercator

bundesl <- spTransform(bundesl, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "))

bundesl_map <- fortify(bundesl, region="RS")

# only doing this bit to plot the RS # at the center of each polygon
# totally not necessary for the choropleth

egg <- cbind(egg, data.frame(gCentroid(bundesl, byid=TRUE)))

gg <- ggplot()

# this bit ensures you have the outlines

gg <- gg + geom_map(data=bundesl_map, map=bundesl_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#7f7f7f", size=0.15)

# this bit here does your choropleth

gg <- gg + geom_map(data=egg, map=bundesl_map,
                    aes(fill=Tariff, map_id=RS),
                    color="#7f7f7f", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + geom_text(data=egg, aes(x=x, y=y, label=RS), size=3)
gg <- gg + coord_equal() # we already projected it
gg <- gg + scale_fill_continuous(name=expression(Tariff), 
                                 low="red", high="green", space="Lab", 
                                 na.value="white", guide="colourbar")
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)

# decent map theme 

gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text=element_blank())


gt <- tableGrob(cbind(bundesl@data[,c(2,4)], egg[,2]))

grid.arrange(gg, gt, ncol=2)
```

[image]

`08` & `16` have unicode in them, hence the lack of display without conversion. I also realize the plotting of the `RS` number on the centroid is problematic for Berlin & Brandenburg, but it was to give a general idea, not be perfect.

I'd highly suggest using `cut` to define 5 or 6 standardized breaks for the values vs use a continuous scale.

Comment: Thanks for your help @hrbmstr, your answer clarifies what is going wrong. But I am still unable to solve the actual problem. God help me :(  P.S. Sorry for replying so late, life got in the way. Thanks again.

Comment: @hrbemstr Can you please tell me why did you use spTransform?

Comment: As the comments say, it pre-projects the coordinates to an internationally recognized proper projection for use with Germany. You can get rid of that and either just use `coord_map()` (instead of `coord_equal()`) which will have `ggplot` deal with using a projection for you (and it'll be Mercator by default) or you can use the alternate suggested one in the comments `coord_map("mollweide") `. Without either `coord_map` or `spTransform` + `coord_equal` you'll have a map that skews to the plot dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. I think I´ll stay with sptransform.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but since it is the best question about germany choropleth maps, I wanted to add a few things i learned while following @hrbrmstr's great answer.

As you can see in the map he plotted, Berlin is just getting the color of Brandenburg. To fix this, the order in the bundesl_map has to be edited, to make sure the Berlin (10) comes after Brandenburg (11). So the full processing of the map should look like this:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)

bundesl <- readOGR("vg2500_geo84/vg2500_bld.shp", "vg2500_bld")
bundesl@data<- bundesl@data[order(bundesl$RS, na.last=NA),]
bundesl_map <- fortify(bundesl, region="RS")
bundesl_map <- rbind(
    bundesl_map[bundesl_map$id != 10, ], 
    bundesl_map[bundesl_map$id == 10, ]
)
saveRDS(bundesl_map, "bundesland")
```

In the last step we save the map for future use (`bundesl_map  <- readRDS("budesland")`). [Here is a copy of the file I created with named ids.](http://mrloh.se/assets/doc/bundesland)

The plotting can also be made a bit more concise as follows:

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

egg %>% ggplot(aes(fill=Tariff, map_id=RS)) +
    geom_map(map=bundesl_map, color="white", size=0.2) + 
    geom_text(aes(x=x, y=y, label=egg$RS), size=2, color="white") +
    coord_map("mercator") +
    expand_limits(x=bundesl_map$long, y=bundesl_map$lat) +
    scale_fill_viridis(begin=0.4, end=0.9, breaks=-8:7, guide=guide_legend(reverse=T)) + 
    theme_map(base_size=8)
```

where `theme_map` is defined as:

```
theme_map <- function(...) {
    theme_classic(...) %+replace% 
    theme(
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        line=element_blank()
    )
}
```

This will yield a map like this:

[image: map]